# Kill specific started process in Windows

Tags: windows, command-line, python, cmd.exe

How can I kill a process of which I don't know the PID or imagename?

So in my Powershell or CMD terminal I can start a process using this command I've botched togheter.

```
cmd.exe /c start /min python .\program_name.py
```

So my understanding is that the first part is: `cmd.exe /c` which starts a new CMD terminal that runs the rest of the command and the terminates.

The next part is: `start /min` that starts the python process minimized from the new CMD terminal.

And last part is: `python .\program_name.py` which simply starts the process. In my case this process is continuous with no return call.

So how do I kill this process? I'm trying to kill it using the `program_name.py` or somehow add a title to the new CMD terminal using title parameter.

I'm using this source for [CMD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/515380/7916220) and this source for [start](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/start)

[Image of the process which for some reason starts 3 subprocesses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfYKh.png)

Answer (score 2):

If you have only one such process, you may kill the executable:

```
taskkill /im python.exe
```

If the process is stubborn and doesn't terminate, add the
`/f` parameter to forcefully terminate the process.

For more information see
[taskkill](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/taskkill).

Comment: `or imagename` .. yes, you DID know the image name (as @harrymc points out).  Script languages use an interpreter which in this case is pyton.exe.  If you have multiple things running under python, this will kill all of them.  If this is the case, your will have to be far more creative.  Perhaps the windows title option for `taskkill` might help in this case.

Comment: @harrymc thanks for your answer, however I do not want to kill all python processes, only the specific one that was created by the command.

Comment: You may take note of the title of the displayed windows, then use `taskkill /F /FI "WindowTitle eq the title" /T`. Beware of hidden blanks in the title. You could also try to give the window a title yourself by adding the title on the `start` command: `start "mytitle" ...` then use `taskkill /F /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq mytitle" /T`.